# Updating standard object contact in Visualforce using a force.com site

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, standard-objects, standardcontroller

I have an issue with updating `contact` standard object in a force.com site. I am using a standard controller for contact in a VF page. The issue is that when I pass id to the force.com site, it simply removes the save button from the page automatically.

With regards to permissions, I have granted read and create access to the profile and also granted field level permissions. I also created a sharing rule for `contact` to share it with guest user profile. Any advice/workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

**Visualforce Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" >
      <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock title="Contact">
         <!--Input form -->
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Firstname}" ignoreEditPermissionForRendering="true"  />
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Lastname}" ignoreEditPermissionForRendering="true"/>
         <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.Email}" ignoreEditPermissionForRendering="true"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>  
      </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**No save button in force.com site after passing Id**

[image]

Comment: How new is this org? It's probably enforcing the latest security restrictions on the guest user, which blocks Update perms.

Comment: Hi David, yes you’re right. I already found the answer to this question. Standard controllers simply doesn’t solve the purpose and I have to use custom controllers to update the standard objects using a force.com site. I tried it for opportunity and it works. The reason why I edited the question is because I was banned from asking questions.

Comment: Feel free to self-answer for anyone else with the same problem!